# Parse the map using a json file. Unable to figure out syntax for reading the operations

Tags: java, json, config

Consider the following function -

```
List<String> CheckMapUsingJson(){

        //Preparing sample Map
        Map<String,Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap.put("name","Simon Smith (Lawyer)");
        dataMap.put("age",40);
        dataMap.put("country","America");

        //Preparing profession list
        List<String> professionList = new ArrayList<>();
        professionList.add("Doctor");
        professionList.add("Lawyer");

        // Output condition list
        List<String> conditionList = new ArrayList<>();


        // If-Else Logic Block
        if(professionList.contains(dataMap.get("name").toString())){
            conditionList.add("P");
            if(Integer.parseInt(dataMap.get("age").toString())%2==0){
                conditionList.add("E");
                if(dataMap.get("country").equals("America")){
                    conditionList.add("A");
                }
                else{
                    conditionList.add("NA");
                }
            }
            else{
                conditionList.add("NE");
            }
        }
        else{
            conditionList.add("NP");
        }
        return conditionList;
    }
```

The above function does a simple task of parsing the map and then preparing the eligibility list. As this is a small example, nested if-elses are small in number.
I want to eradicate the use of the nested if elses and use a config file as follows. This is for only one map key-

```
{
  "name": 
  {"match values":["Doctor","Lawyer"],
  "operator":"contains",
  "output values":{"notmatch":"NP","match":"P"}
},
  "age":
  {"match values":0,
    "operator":"%",
    "output values":{"notmatch":"NE","match":"E"}}
}
```

Can someone expand, or tell me how I can make use of this json config structure to perform the same operations as the if-else block? I want to make this config file reusable , so that it can be used in other instances too.
I'm unable to figure out the syntax

Comment: It sounds like you are asking two separate questions, but assuming there is one single unified answer. Question (1) How to read JSON data from a file into one or more Java objects. Question (2) How to eliminate/minimize/restructure your `if` statements. JSON doesn't "perform operations" - it's just data, so even if you have an answer for (1), that would not resolve any part of (2). You can clarify of course, if I have misunderstood - which is always a possibility.

Comment: Use ObjectMapper instead ... makes things WAY easier ;)